# Integrity Error: NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I created a custom create field in the tournament serializer to create and update nested field.
I have been trying to make that work for a long time, but I can't get rid of errors.

When I try to post data on the tournament update it returns this error:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: api_tournament.organizer_id
```

Here, api is the name of the app.

models.py

```
class tournament(models.Model):
    tournament_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    organizer = models.ForeignKey(
        client, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    logo = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=False)
    game = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=GAMES)
    fees = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
# tournament

@api_view(['GET'])
def tournamentList(request):
    tournaments = tournament.objects.all()
    serializer = tournamentSerializer(tournaments, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['GET'])
def tournamentDetail(request, tournamentId):
    singleTournament = tournament.objects.get(tournament_id=tournamentId)
    serializer = tournamentSerializer(singleTournament, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['POST'])
def tournamentCreate(request):
    serializer = tournamentSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['POST'])
def tournamentUpdate(request, tournamentId):
    singleTournament = tournament.objects.get(tournament_id=tournamentId)
    serializer = tournamentSerializer(
        instance=singleTournament, data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['DELETE'])
def tournamentDelete(request, tournamentId):
    singleTournament = tournament.objects.get(tournament_id=tournamentId)
    singleTournament.delete()

    return Response("Deleted Item")
```

serializers.py

```
class tournamentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    organizer = clientSerializer(many=False, read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = tournament
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        organizer_data = validated_data.pop('organizer')
        new_tournament = tournament.objects.create(**validated_data)
        client.objects.create(organizer_data)
        return new_tournament
```

Comment: Please edit your question to bring more focus to it. Remove all the unnecessary code. If you're interested in errors provoked by `tournamentUpdate` calls only why would we read all the other api views code?

Comment: Thanku, for the suggestion I removed the unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0):

1. "I created cusotm create field in the tournament serializer to create and update nested field, trying to make that work for a long time now but can't get rid of errors."

This error has nothing to do with create/update nested fields. But if you really go down that road:

When you initialize a serializer with an instance and call save(), it's not going to call the create method. It'll call the serializer update method. Here is the source code for proof.

```
        if self.instance is not None:
            self.instance = self.update(self.instance, validated_data)
            assert self.instance is not None, (
                '`update()` did not return an object instance.'
            )
        else:
            self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
            assert self.instance is not None, (
                '`create()` did not return an object instance.'
            )

        return self.instance
```

But the serializer update method does not seem to be in the code you provided. It'll default to the ModelSerializer's update, which  would raise an error about nested writes. Since that's not what happened, the bug must be earlier. This probably happened inside serializer.is_valid().

2. "When I try to post data on the tournament update it gives the error as

`NOT NULL constraint failed: api_tournament.organizer_id`
"

The error says that a constraint preventing null values has been violated. From the looks of it, the request.data might not have an "organizer_id" or "organizer" key. If you want to update a tournament without posting all the data during an update, either give the serializer field argument required=False or initialize the serializer with the argument partial=True

Comment: _"the request.data might not have an "organizer_id" or "organizer" key"_, there is no field like __organizer id__ and, _"serializer field argument required=False or initialize the serializer with the argument partial=True"_, this __didn't work__